# Integrating gapps into the new rom im installing

Tags: cyanogenmod, titanium-backup

I have the recovery file for my S4 mini and I have the new CyanogenMod ROM downloaded on my external SD along with my update file and gapps zip file but i'm not sure how to integrate the titanium update file into my ROM or do I just restart my phone and open that zip once the rom is installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can normally install that zip through recovery itself once the ROM is done installing. So the steps would be:

- Go into recovery.
- Flash ROM.
- Flash GApps.
- Flash the titanium update.zip (just the way you flashed ROM and GApps).
- Clear dalvic cache and cache.
- Reboot.

Hope this helps.

Comment: THank you :) Just to be clear what exactly is flash?

Comment: "Flash" here refers to normal install (that task of "installing zip" in recovery is what is referred to as flash). Shortening my answer, install ROM and GApps and then install that titanium update.zip just the same way as you installed ROM.